# Path name too long, error when trying to save image with OpenCV or PIL.Image in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, save, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save an image as:

```
img_path = folder_path + "\\image1.png"
```

folder_path exists, as I previously check it:

```
if(not os.path.exists(folder_path)):
    raise OSError("Directory does not exist") #doesn't raise error
```

I have tried with OpenCV

```
cv2.imwrite(img_path, img)
```

But it doesn't create the image, as when I do

```
if(not os.path.exists(img_path)):
    raise OSError("Image not saved correctly.") #raises error
```

It raises the error, and when looking to the folder, the image is not there.
I have also tried with PIL.Image

```
img.save(img_path)
```

Which gives a FileNotFoundError.

I think the problem is that folder_path is too long (it has 279 characters), as when I try to save the image to another folder it saves it correctly. I don't think there is a permission problem. Is there any way to create some kind of "shortcut" for the OS that the name of the path may be shorter? It's important for the images to be saved at that path.

Comment: If it really is the folder path length that is the issue, you can try giving relative path from your python script (if that makes it shorter).

Comment: os has this limitation of path length, shorten the file name and the folder names on the way, or save it to D:\tmp and move it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, changing the working directory with `os.chdir(folder_path)`, then just save the image as `cv2.imwrite("image1.png")`.